# Splunk : extract multiple values from each event

Tags: splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am new to Splunk queries and I am not able to figure out how to extract multiple values from same event. I am working with events that look like this :

```
...
starting count: 12345678
ending count: 12347890
total time: ...
....
```

I want to extract the values associated with "starting count" and "ending count" and create a chart comparing these two values.
So far I am able to extract one set of value using this query

```
rex field=_raw "starting count: (?<StartCount>\d+)"
```

But how can I extract two different values and compare? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are going to make a chart that means you have multiple events and each event contains a starting count and ending count?

Comment: `| rex field=_raw "starting count: (?<StartCount>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "ending count: (?<EndCount>\d+)"
| eval difference=EndCount-StartCount
| table _time StartCount EndCount difference`

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. I did came up with something similar to what you proposed. Thank you very much @JerryJeremiah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to make a chart, does that means you have multiple events and each event contains a starting count and ending count?

If so, extract the starting count and the ending count with a `rex` (just like you suggested) and then `eval` the difference.  Somthing like:

```
| rex field=_raw "starting count: (?<StartCount>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "ending count: (?<EndCount>\d+)"
| eval difference=EndCount-StartCount
| table _time StartCount EndCount difference
```

Here is a "run anywhere" version that makes it's own test data:

```
| makeresults count=2
| streamstats count
| eval _raw=if(count=1,"starting count: 12345678 ending count: 12346789 total time: ...","starting count: 12347890 ending count: 12349999 total time: ...")
| eval _time=if(count=1,_time-1,_time)

| rex field=_raw "starting count: (?<StartCount>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "ending count: (?<EndCount>\d+)"
| eval difference=EndCount-StartCount
| table _time StartCount EndCount difference
```